# How to run blocking Java code concurrently in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, jooq

I'm working on a new side project with a goal of more deeply learning Kotlin, and I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to mix Kotlin-style concurrency with code not written with coroutines in mind (JOOQ in this case). The function below is in one of my DAOs, and in that map block, I want to update a bunch of rows in the DB. In this specific example, the updates are actually dependent on the previous one completing, so it will need to be done sequentially, but I'm interested in how this code could be modified to run the updates in parallel, since there will undoubtedly be use cases I have that don't need to be run sequentially.

```
suspend fun updateProductChoices(choice: ProductChoice) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    ctx().transaction { config ->
        val tx = DSL.using(config)

        val previousRank = tx.select(PRODUCT_CHOICE.RANK)
                .from(PRODUCT_CHOICE)
                .where(PRODUCT_CHOICE.STORE_PRODUCT_ID.eq(choice.storeProductId))
                .and(PRODUCT_CHOICE.PRODUCT_ID.eq(choice.productId))
                .fetchOne(PRODUCT_CHOICE.RANK)

        (previousRank + 1..choice.rank).map { rank ->
            tx.update(PRODUCT_CHOICE)
                    .set(PRODUCT_CHOICE.RANK, rank - 1)
                    .where(PRODUCT_CHOICE.PRODUCT_ID.eq(choice.productId))
                    .and(PRODUCT_CHOICE.RANK.eq(rank))
                    .execute()
        }
    }
}
```

Would the best way be to wrap the `transaction` lambda in `runBlocking` and each `update` in an `async`, then `awaitAll` the result? Also possibly worth noting that the JOOQ queries support `executeAsync()` which returns a `CompletionStage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use JOOQ's `executeAsync`. With `executeAsync`, you can remove the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` because the call is no longer blocking.

The `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` library includes coroutines integration with `CompletionStage`, so you can do a suspending `await` on it ([docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/kotlinx.coroutines.future/java.util.concurrent.-completion-stage/await.html)).

To perform the updates in parallel, note that the same library can convert a `CompletionStage` to a `Deferred` ([docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/kotlinx.coroutines.future/java.util.concurrent.-completion-stage/as-deferred.html)). Therefore, if you change the call to `execute` to `executeAsync().asDeferred()` you will get a list of `Deferred`s, on which you can `awaitAll()`.